# IIS return 200 OK to any request

Tags: iis

How to configure IIS to return 200 OK to any URL request? 
Any request that arrives to IIS should immediately return 200 with an empty body.
It is not important how this is achieved, either thru configuration or code.

Comment: URL Rewrite module allows you to return custom responses with the status codes you like, but whether the body is empty is uncertain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As lex says, we could use url rewrite to achieve your requirement. You could install url rewrite firstly by using this url:https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite.

Then you could add below rule into the web.config.

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
                <rule name="Customresponse" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="200" statusReason="test" statusDescription="test" />
                </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```